# Splunk search - How to loop on multi values field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My use case is analysing ticket in order to attribute a state regarding all the status of a specific ticket.

Raw data look like this :

| Id | Version | Status | Event Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1 | New | 2021-01-07T09:14:00Z |
| 0001 | 1 | Completed - Action Performed | 2021-01-07T09:38:00Z |

Data looks like this after transaction command:

| Id | Version | Status | Event Time | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001, 0001 | 1, 1 | New, Completed - Action Performed | 2021-01-07T09:14:00Z, 2021-01-07T09:38:00Z | Acknowlegdement, Work |

I'm using transcation command in order to calculate the duration of acknnowlegdement and resolution of the ticket.

I have predefine rule to choose the correct state. This rules compare the n-1 status (New), and the current status (Completed - Action Performed) to choose the state.

**Issue**

Each ticket has a different number of status. We can not know in advance the max status number. I can not write a static search comparing each value of the Status field.

**Expected Solution**

I have a field that inform me the number of index on the status (number of status of a ticket) field.

I want to use a loop (Why not a loop for), to iterate on each index of the field Status and compare the value i-1 and i.

I can not find how to do this. Is this possible ?

Thank you

Comment: can you share the _raw_ events, instead of the table of amalgamated events?

Comment: Hi warren, i added raw data :)

Answer (score 1):

### Update to reflect more details

Here's a method with [`streamstats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/streamstats) that should get you *towards* an answer:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp Id=* Version=* Status=* EventTime=* state=*
| eval phash=sha256(Version.Status)
| sort 0 _time
| streamstats current=f last(phash) as chash by Id state
| fillnull value="noprev"
| eval changed=if(chash!=phash OR chash="noprev","true","false")
| search NOT changed="false"
| table *
```

#### original answer

Something like the following should work to get the most-recent status:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp Id=* Version=* Status=* EventTime=* state=*
| stats latest(Status) as Status latest(Version) as Version latest(state) state latest(EventTime) as "Event Time" by Id
```

#### edit in light of mentioning g the `transaction` command

Don't use `transaction` unless you really *really* ***really*** need to.

99% of the time, `stats` will accomplish what `transaction` does faster and more efficiently.

For example:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp Id=* Version=* Status=* EventTime=* state=*
| stats earliest(Status) as eStatus latest(Status) as lStatus earliest(Version) as eVersion latest(Version) as lVersion earliest(status) as estate latest(state) lstate earliest(EventTime) as Opened latest(EventTime) as MostRecent by Id
```

Will yield a table you can then manipulate further with `eval` and such. Eg (presuming the time format is subtractable (ie still in Unix epoch format)):

```
| eval ticketAge=MostRecent-Opened
| eval Versions=eVersion+" - "+lVersion
| eval Statuses=eStatus+" - "+lStatus
| eval State=estate+", ",lstate
| eval Opened=strftime(Opened,"%c"), MostRecent=strftime(MostRecent,"%c")
| eval D=if(ticketAge>86400,round(ticketAge/86400),0)
| eval ticketAge=if(D>0,round(ticketAge-(D*86400)),ticketAge)
| eval H=if(ticketAge>3600,round(ticketAge/3600),0)
| eval ticketAge=if(H>0,round(ticketAge-(H*3600)),ticketAge)
| eval M=if(ticketAge>60,round(ticketAge/60),0)
| eval ticketAge=if(M>0,round(ticketAge-(M*60)),ticketAge)
| rename ticketAge as S
| eval Age=D+" days "+H+" hours"+M+" minutes"+S+" seconds"
| table Id Versions Statuses Opened MostRecent State Age
| rename MostRecent as "Most Recent"
```

---

Note: I may have gotten the conversion from raw seconds into days, hours, minutes, seconds off - but it should be close

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. This is not working, because the field state is not existing in the raw data. I added this field with comparaison. And your search only provide state comparing the first and last status. I wanted to provide a state at each changement of status. my data should have different state as it has different status

Comment: @ClementRos - in that case, you'll want to look at `streamstats`. I'll try to give an example soon as I can. Please update your question to reflect the additional information you've shared in this comment :)

Comment: I tried to used steamstats and eventstats but was only able to get the first and the last status value by ID, not the current status and the previous

Comment: @ClementRos - please see update and let me know if that gets you closer